# How to formalize rules on what's a proper name?

Tags: derivation, proper-nouns

**TL;DR: Why do I have trouble deciding what is a proper name and how can I find a reasonable set of rules to follow when deciding?**

I’m a member of a team responsible for the National Photocorpus of the Polish Language, where we are trying to confirm the earliest existence of any given Polish word in print (within certain period).

We have recently reviewed some of those we have rejected or marked as problematic, and turns out that the lemmata I had treated as proper names are considered common names by my colleagues. I don't know the literature in this particular field, and I find it problematic to generate a consistent rule set.

Having in mind that proper names in principle name singular objects, we have cases like Ford (a company) and Ford (each of that company’s cars). So that's one problem. Another problem is derivation—it's much richer in Polish, so it doesn’t always translate well, but let me try:

```
PL: Nowy Jork → Nowojorczyk

EN: New York → New Yorker

PL: Anglia → Anglik

EN: England → Englishman
```

Here both are treated as proper names. But in Polish it’s easy to make a name of an employee or member of an institution:

```
PL: PPS (Polish Socialist Party) → pepeesowiec (its member)

EN: IRS → *IRSian, *IRSer

EN: Google → Googler
```

My colleagues say that such a person is now described with a common name. But why? It is still derived from a proper name and refers to multiple units.

To me that should directly transpose itself onto Byronian (enthusiast of his works) or Francophobe (hater of the French); at the very least, I would see a third, middle-ground category: *proper name-derived common names* with semantics somewhere in between.

Comment: I have a feeling this comes down to defining first what is a 'common name' and what a 'proper name'—and if you feel a third category in between is required, you'll need to define that, too. Otherwise the science becomes mushy, and it will be harder for you to get the point across. You can use a something similar to this question to justify your approach.

Comment: @dumetrulo that's why I want to use some (widely) accepted definitions to be able to do that.